# How can I calculate the optimaized amount of operations I can execute in one batch process in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, batch-insert

I am writing a process which is supposed to enter many nodes\properties\relationships to Neo4j.
How can I know what is the optimized\max number I can add to one batch?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

As always: "it depends".

In practice I've found 10k - 100k atomic operations a good value.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And is the calculation linked directly to the server's spec? Another following question, is where you referring to batch insert with  rest api?

Comment: The calculation is mostly driven by available heap size. Batch sizes are mostly determined on client side.

Comment: Thank you. A following question is that I'm using rest apis for this action - is this the best way?